# How to use the PNP Framework to authenticate client credentials in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/app"))
            {
                SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("Admin@sample.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

                context.Load(context.Web, x => x.Url);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

             }
```

This is my old code block and this is working Azure "security default" disabled environment.

When I run this in an environment with Azure security default enabled, an error appears. I need to use a code block connected to the PNP framework to execute this code. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetACSAppOnlyContext to access SharePoint online. Please refer to following code

```
  string siteUrl = "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/demo"; 
  string clientId = "*******-****-4818-a928-f14658a9fe90"; 
  string clientSecret = "*****************"; 
  using (var clientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientId, clientSecret))
  {
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, p => p.Title);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(clientContext.Web.Title);
  };
```

Comment: HI @RaytheonXie-MSFT, Thank you for the response. I have check this and when it execute, it gave me 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'. Any input on this.